Prometheus promQL single label matcher empty value
I was going through promQL querying basics and noticed a statement which does not make sense.
In contrast, these expressions are valid as they both have a selector that does not match empty label values.

{job=~".+"}              # Good!
{job=~".*",method="get"} # Good!

The documentation says that a vector selector should specify at least one label matcher that does not match with empty value. However, the below vector selector does not have a name, also it has just one label matcher that matches with empty value.
{job=~".+"}
can you help me understand why the documentations says it's a valid selector?
ref: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/
I tried to find the difference between .* and .+ . I found one reference https://docs.logz.io/docs/user-guide/infrastructure-monitoring/introduction-to-prometheus/promql-query/ which says .* is not allowed in promQL but I see it used everywhere.

.+ doesn't match empty string. String must contain at least one symbol to be matched by .+.
